# Webhook response when updates happen in evernote

Tags: evernote

I am using evernote with my application, with webhooks. If any updates happen in note, I will get a response in query params like

```
"guid": "045d3f4e-3b5a-4096-8d03-09dba59ac606",
"notebookGuid": "58f761a8-dfbb-4387-986e-2a82db3a4fc3",
"reason": "update",
"userId": "602849"
```

With this data I am unable to get current updated information.
Can anyone suggest how to resolve my problem. Quick help is needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I improved your grammar and the format of your response to make your question easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the latest note, use [NoteStore#getNote](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNote) with the guid you got from the webhook.

Comment: HI,Thanks for the reply.My intention is to get recent update happened in the note.

Comment: The Evernote API doesn't provide any information on what specifically changed. In order to know that, you'd need to keep a copy of the note in a data store of your own, and then when you get the webhook, do the getNote call that kentaro mentioned and compare the properties of your saved copy with the values you get back from getNote.